# (NLM @ Circular TimeSeries model ) == invalid phase confidence intervals

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, time-series

In the realm of TimeSeries of data with Circular Statistics, NonlinearModelFit (NLM) correctly generates reasonable Standard Error & confidence intervals for phase parameters (phaseCIs) with x-values that are integer offsets from a reference time (TRef).  However, when AbsoluteTime values are utilized, resulting  NLM Standard Error for phaseCIs are nonsensical.  NOTE: I'm aware of FittedModel::constr warning, but still...

Questions:

1. Why does NLM  ignore parameter constraints Abs[phi] <= 2Pi when AbsoluteTime units are utilized?
2. Is there an additional NLM tuning parameter to ensure Phi never steps outside its constrained param value?
3. Is there a two-pass strategy to get reasonable phaseCIs (e.g., estimate BestFitParameters in one pass with a specific NLM Method, and then run a second NLM passing with a Method that explicitly applies parameter constraints)?
4. (More generally) What other issues does NLM have with respect to TimeSeries data with Circular Statistical models?

```
(* Globals *)
{dayAsSeconds, lunarDayAsSeconds} = 
  QuantityMagnitude @  
     UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Hours"], "Seconds"] & /@ {24, 24.8};
TRef = DateObject@ {2021, 1, 12, 0, 0} ;
deltaT = 
  QuantityMagnitude @  UnitConvert[Quantity[30, "Minutes"], "Seconds"];
(* Define xValues, one with TRef offset, the other AbsoluteTime *)
xAsOffsets =  Range[5 dayAsSeconds, 20 dayAsSeconds , deltaT ];
xAsAbsoluteTime = 
  AbsoluteTime[TRef + Quantity[#, "Seconds"] ] & /@ xAsOffsets;
```

NOTE: At this point, the only difference between xAsOffsets and xAsAbsoluteTime is their IntegerLength[] size: the former are offset values from a TRef {0, 3600, ...} with IntegerLength[] <= 7 whereas the latter are AbsoluteTime values {3819830400, 3819832200, ...} whose IntegerLength[] == 10.  Both are monotonically increasing by 1800.

```
(* Model *)
model = M + A1 Cos[2 Pi (t / tau1) + phi1] +   
   A2 Cos[2 Pi (t / tau2) + phi2] ;
modelSeeds =  { M -> 100, A1 -> 10, tau1 -> dayAsSeconds, 
   phi1 -> - Pi/4, A2 -> 2, tau2 -> lunarDayAsSeconds, 
   phi2 -> - Pi/4};
SeedRandom[1];
rnd[dummy_] := 5 RandomReal [{-.5, .5}];
(* Generate xyPairs *)
xyAsOffset = 
  Table[{t, (model /. modelSeeds) + rnd[t]} , {t, xAsOffsets }];
xyAsAbsoluteTime = 
  Table[{t, (model /. modelSeeds) + rnd[t]} , {t, xAsAbsoluteTime }];
(* Prepare NLM wrapper *)
nlmParms = { {M}, {A1}, {tau1, dayAsSeconds}, {phi1, Pi}, {A2}, {tau2,
     lunarDayAsSeconds}, {phi2, Pi}};
nlmConstraint = 
  Abs[phi1] <= 2 Pi && Abs[phi2] <= 2 Pi && A1 > 0 && A2 > 0;
nlm[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[NonlinearModelFit]] := 
 nlm[data, opts] = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, nlmConstraint}, nlmParms, t, opts];
```

Visually verify both computed dataset Y-values are in the same phase

```
ListPlot[{xyAsOffset[[All, 2]], xyAsAbsoluteTime[[All, 2]]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Confirming both datasets are in phase]

Visually compare phi1 and phi2 Standard Error and Confidence Intervals to see the crazy phaseCIs for xyAsAbsoluteTime.

```
compareCIResults[opts : OptionsPattern[NonlinearModelFit]] := 
 TableForm[{#["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"] & /@ {nlm[
      xyAsOffset, opts], nlm[xyAsAbsoluteTime, opts]}}, 
  TableHeadings -> {{opts}, {"xAsOffsetsFromTRef", 
     "xAsAbsoluteTime"}}];
compareCIResults[]
```

[image: Comparison of ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable]

Comment: You might get more help if you removed some of the unnecessary information.  For example replacing `xAsOffset` and `xAsAbsoluteTime` as `x1` and `x2` with `x1 = 432000 + 1800 Range[0, 720];` and `x2 =x1 + 3819398400;`.  The issue you raise is legit.  It's just clouded by a lot of unnecessary information.  And I don't think this qualifies as "circular statistics" or whatever a "circular time series" is just because cosines are involved.  It's simply a regression with an additive error.

Answer (score 3):

This (for me) has been challenging but in essence, given the data and model, the parameters `phi1` and `tau1` are almost perfectly correlated (as are `phi2` and `tau2`) which means one can set `phi1` and `phi2` to any value and you'll get an almost identical fit.  So the "crazy" standard errors are due to the overparameterization of the model rather than any error in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Consider an example that exactly matches your data generation and model.

```
(* Specify model and parameter values of interest *)
model = m + a1 Cos[2 Pi t/(10^4 tau1) + phi1 ] + 
   a2 Cos[2 Pi t/(10^4 tau2) + phi2 ];
parameters = {m -> 100, a1 -> 10, tau1 -> 8.64, a2 -> 2, 
   tau2 -> 8.928, phi1 -> -π/4, phi2 -> -π/4};
```

Note that I've scaled `tau1` and `tau2` so that all parameters are
nearly the same order of magnitude which is generally good practice
and tends to give one more numerically stable results.

```
(* Specify predictor values *)
n = 701;
x = 381830400 + 1800 Range[0, n];

(* Generate response *)
SeedRandom[12345];
error = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-2.5, 2.5}], n + 1];
y = (model /. parameters /. t -> x) + error;
xy = Transpose[{x, y}];

(* Fit regression *)
restrictions = {a1 > 0, a2 > 0, tau1 > 0, tau2 > 0};
(* Model fitting all parameters *)
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[xy, {model, restrictions}, 
  {{m, 100}, {a1, 10}, {tau1, 8.64}, {phi1, -Pi/4},
     {a2, 2}, {tau2, 8.928}, {phi2, -Pi/4}}, t] // Quiet;
(* Model fixing phi1 and phi2 - doesn't matter what values are used *)   
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[xy, {model /. {phi1 -> 1, phi2 -> 1}, restrictions},
    {{m, 100}, {a1, 10}, {tau1, 8.64}, {a2, 2}, {tau2, 8.928}}, t] // Quiet;
```

The fits are nearly identical.

```
(* Show results *)
Show[Plot[{nlm1[t], nlm2[t]}, {t, Min[x], Max[x]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{LightGray, Thickness[0.01]}, {Red, Thickness[0.0005]}}],
  ListPlot[xy], AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: Data and fits]

(One fit is in light gray with a wider line and the other fit is in red.)

To justify the claim that `phi1` and `tau1` (and `phi2` and `tau2`) are nearly perfectly correlated consider the correlation matrix from `nlm1` above (where all parameters were fit):

```
NumberForm[nlm1["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm, 3]
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

There are other highly correlated estimators.  In fact, all parameters except `m` are highly correlated with each other which can indicate numerical instability in the estimates of those parameters.

Comment: JimB -- Thank you for simplifying this model -- and educating me on the correct strategy for generating the random error correctly!  That said, off-line I'll re-work the example and if I may, send directly to you so that I'm clear about your point with the over-parameterization.

Comment: JimB -- ALSO thanks for pointing out the tip of rescaling Tau1 and Tau2 -- more for me to fold into on-going tests here as I explore your response further here.